# YA fantasy book series featuring a wizard's apprentice in a time-looped castle

Tags: story-identification, books, time-travel, young-adult, wizards

I read this series in the early 2000s, and I believe the main character's name was Randall. He was a wizard's apprentice (I think), and in one of the books (potentially the third?), he enters a castle where time is distorted. Over the course of the book he sees himself several times, before finally realising that the figure he met at the start of the book when he entered was himself in disguise. He then dons a hood to mask his identity, and gives something to the version of himself now entering the castle that he received at the start, completing the time loop, before leaving. He then wonders if the time loop will continue eternally.

I don't have any more detail than this unfortunately, and not being able to find this has been bothering me for years.

Comment: Your question has been marked as a Duplicate. This is not a censure, just part of our police regarding [tag:story-identification] questions that have the same accepted answer. You will still get points for upvotes, and people can still leave comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this Debra Doyle's ***[Circle of Magic](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/363042.School_of_Wizardry)*** series...?

- Book 1: *[School of Wizardry](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/363042.School_of_Wizardry)* (1990)
- Book 2: *[Secret of the Tower](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/366743.Secret_of_the_Tower)* (1990)
- Book 3: *[The Wizard's Statue](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/363036.The_Wizard_s_Statue)* (1990)
- Book 4: *[Danger in the Palace](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/363037.Danger_in_the_Palace)* (1990)
- Book 5: *[The Wizard's Castle](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/18887203-the-wizard-s-castle)* (1990)
- Book 6: *[The High King's Daughter](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/366753.The_High_King_s_Daughter)* (1990)
- Book 7: *[Mystery at Wizardry School](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/11299015-mystery-at-wizardry-school)* (2003)
- Book 8: *[A Voz do Gelo](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/6976508-a-voz-do-gelo)* (2003)

According to the [articles4deletion wiki](https://a4d.fandom.com/wiki/Circle_of_Magic_(Doyle_and_Macdonald_novels)), the series' protagonist is a wizard's apprentice named Randal of Doun.

> *Circle of Magic*, also known as *The Wizard's Apprentice* in the United Kingdom, is a series of eight junior novels written by Debra Doyle and James D. Macdonald. The books are set in a high-fantasy pseudo-medieval era. **The series protagonist is young squire Randal of Doun, whose life is changed forever when he meets the Master Wizard, Madoc The Wayfarer, and forsakes his home to pursue the study of magic. The series chronicles his apprenticeship at the Schola Sorceriae, the School of Wizardry, through his status of Journeyman and finally to his rise as a full Master of the Art.**

Someone asked a [story-ID question](https://www.goodreads.com/topic/show/22150813-solved-ya-fantasy-series-teen-magician-expelled-from-magical-school-fo) about the series on Goodreads and mentioned that the plot of the fifth book, *The Wizard's Castle*, involves a spell that seals a castle into an infinite time loop.

> The fifth? book is about a siege where the main character is assisting the besieging forces while another expelled magician is inside the castle; **it ends with the other magician fumbling a time loop spell that seals the castle into its own infinite time loop.**
>
> [image: Front cover of "The Wizard's Castle" (1990) by Debra Doyle.]

Comment: Absolutely correct! I have literally searched for "Wizard's Apprentice" before because that's what I thought it was called, and not gotten this result. Thank you!